# error for gdbserver

Tags: linux, gdb, embedded-linux, gdbserver

Anybody knows the error message?
gdbserver[949] segfault at 81c ip 0000081c sp bfeef918 error 4 in gdbserver [8048000+1c0000]
segmentation fault

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message (presumably from `/var/log/messages`) means that `gdbserver` crashed (received `SIGSEGV`).

I think it happened at instruction `0x81c`, which likely means that it called a function though bad function pointer.